# PrestoDB SELECT * from table - error

Tags: hadoop, presto

I am getting following exception on prestoserver when I run query "SELECT * from TABLE"

Can you please help?

Exception on server:

05_00000_yzbvk.1
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Response is null.; Host Details : local host is: "ubuntu/192.168.56.101"; destination host is: "examples.net":54310;
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplitIterable$HiveSplitQueue.computeNext(HiveSplitIterable.java:433) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplitIterable$HiveSplitQueue.computeNext(HiveSplitIterable.java:392) ~[na:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.startTasks(SqlStageExecution.java:463) [presto-main-0.54.jar:0.54]
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.access$300(SqlStageExecution.java:80) [presto-main-0.54.jar:0.54]
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution$5.run(SqlStageExecution.java:435) [presto-main-0.54.jar:0.54]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Response is null.; Host Details : local host is: "ubuntu/192.168.56.101"; destination host is: "examples.net":54310;
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:763) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1229) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202) ~[na:na]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.getListing(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83) ~[na:na]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.getListing(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:441) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:1526) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:1509) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:406) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1462) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1502) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.ForwardingFileSystem.listStatus(ForwardingFileSystem.java:298) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.ForwardingFileSystem.listStatus(ForwardingFileSystem.java:298) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.FileSystemWrapper$3.listStatus(FileSystemWrapper.java:146) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.(FileSystem.java:1778) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1777) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1760) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.DirectoryLister$FastLister.list(DirectoryLister.java:69) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.DirectoryLister.listDirectory(DirectoryLister.java:41) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.AsyncRecursiveWalker$1.run(AsyncRecursiveWalker.java:56) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.SuspendingExecutor$1.run(SuspendingExecutor.java:67) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.BoundedExecutor.executeOrMerge(BoundedExecutor.java:82) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.BoundedExecutor.access$000(BoundedExecutor.java:41) ~[na:na]
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.BoundedExecutor$1.run(BoundedExecutor.java:53) ~[na:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
java.io.IOException: Response is null.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a configuration problem.

In file etc/config.properties, you left default value :

```
discovery.uri=http://example.net:54310
```

Modify it to

```
discovery.uri=http://localhost:54310
```